# How to render show action as a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a search form. when i search for a record, the result goes to the show page as expected , but i want the result to render on the same page where ever i put the form partial

I want to create a partial that will render the show action on the same page with the form

Here is the shipment controller

```
class shipmentsController < ApplicationController
  def show
   @shipment = Shipment.find_by_trackCode(params["trackCode"])
    unless @shipment.present? 
    end

 ......
```

Home controller index.html.erb

```
<%=render 'shipments/form' %>
```

Views/shipments/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag search_path, :controller => 'shipments', :action => 'show',          :method => 'get' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :trackCode %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Track' %>
 <% end %>
```

The present code will dispaly the result on the show page but I want the search result to be rendered using a partial so that i can render it where ever i use the form partial.

How can i archive that ?

Answer (score 0):

are you really sure it's a good idea to use your show view as a partial? now if you are... you could rename your file _show.html.erb and reference it passing the folder name <%=render 'shipments/show' %> but you'd also have to change the loop to call the model Shipment.all.each instead of @shipment

Answer (score 0):

```
render template: 'shipments/show', locals: {shipment: @shipment}
```

use variable shipment instead of @shipment in show.html.haml